# Why PyAutoGUI's "locateCenterOnScreen()" function have different results in different environments？

Tags: pyautogui

**Run the following code in the virtual environment of anaconda3:**

```
import pyautogui

img = 'work/IMAGES\IMAGE_2023-12-13-171525.png'
location =  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img, confidence=0.9)
print(location)
```

The path of img is correct and exists. If the image corresponding to the img path on the screen is blocked, an error will be reported:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 172, in wrapper
> return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
> return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 405, in locateOnScreen
> retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 383, in locate
> points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 257, in _locateAll_opencv
> raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image (highest confidence = %.3f)' % result.max())
> pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image (highest confidence = 0.569)
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\ADev\PyCharm 2023.1.2\PyCharm\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 237, in _new_run
> return self.*original_run()
> File "D:\CocoPyRPA_QT\CocoPyRPA-QT\src\main\newWindow.py", line 1461, in run
> mainWork(self, self.tableWidget, self.action)
> File "D:\CocoPyRPA_QT\CocoPyRPA-QT\src\root\funcCmdMain.py", line 66, in mainWork
> fm.RPA_mouse.clickL(self, rowData)
> File "D:\CocoPyRPA_QT\CocoPyRPA-QT\src\root\PyRPA\functions_mod.py", line 162, in clickL
> mouseClick(self, errorLoop, 'left', clickTime=1, content=content, img=imgName, loop=loop)
> File "D:\CocoPyRPA_QT\CocoPyRPA-QT\src\root\PyRPA\functions_mod.py", line 81, in mouseClick
> a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img, confidence=0.9)
> File "D:\anaconda3\envs\CocoPyRPA\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init**.py", line 174, in wrapper
> raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.
> pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException

**When running the same code above in the system's python3.10.8 environment, no error will be reported, but will return:**
The value of location is None. Is this what is the reason?

**I tried the following code:**

```
import pyautogui
from pyscreeze import ImageNotFoundException

img = 'work/IMAGES\IMAGE_2023-12-13-171525.png' # image file path
pyautogui.useImageNotFoundException() # Force the use of ImageNotFoundException exception
try:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img, confidence=0.9) # Try to find the center coordinates of the image
    print(f"Find the image with coordinates ({x}, {y})")
except ImageNotFoundException: # If not found, catch exception
    print("No image found")
```

**But when the image is blocked, an error will still be reported and the exception will not be captured.**